# CMake can not find PythonLibs

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build [inria Graphite](http://alice.loria.fr/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22) on my ubuntu which is running in a VirtualBox simulator, I follow the instructions, and install the `python-dev` packages, but when I run cmake , still got an error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108          (message):
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
(Required is at least version "3.2")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315     (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
 /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:208 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
 src/packages/OGF/gel_python3/CMakeLists.txt:11 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

I checked the `/usr/lib/` and find

```
tintin@tintin-VirtualBox:/usr/lib$ find . -name "libpython*"
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.a
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.a
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1
```

so why cmake can not find the PythonLibs, or how should I deal with this?

Answer (score 26):

Installing `python-dev` actually fixed this for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Got the hint here: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/484

Comment: Rather than pointing to an external link please copy-paste the relevant portion from there so that if the link is unreachable for some reason the contents are still available here..

Comment: Well, the solution is to run: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: @helgar Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/641432/edit) your answer and add the above command.

Comment: A small note: for Python 3 use `apt-get install python3-dev`. `python-dev` and `python3-dev` are metapackages that pull the most current dev upstream for the selected Python.

Comment: This does not solve the issue in all cases, the answer given by @Job explains why.

Comment: @minerals what answer given by Job?

Comment: Caffe currently only takes 2.7 and won't cmake with python3. If you try to install python3-dev which installs python-is-python3, caffe still throws a `Could NOT find PythonLibs (Required is at least version "2.7")'.  You have to aptitude install python-is-python2 to back it out, and python-dev (version 2), in order for the Caffe cmake to work.

Answer (score 11):

The problem seems to be that Ubuntu 14.04 installs Python 3.4 by default and the CMake version from Ubuntu (2.8) only searches up to Python 3.3. A workaround is to add `set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.4)` before the `find_package` statement. Note that I filed a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cmake/+bug/1323559) about this issue.

Since CMake 3.0, [CMake searches up to Python 3.4](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/ab6201ab647c13fee44c44822b8502e9848faaaf), so installing that version manually should also fix the problem.

Comment: It would be nice to give an explanation about the downvote.

Answer (score 7):

For me the issue was a bad cache

```
rm CMakeCache.txt
```

Removed the cache with the old 2.7 version and allowed it to find 3.2 in my case.

The cmake I used is

```
find_package(PythonInterp 3.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.2 REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES = ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}")
message(STATUS "PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
...
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue with Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit; apparently, CMake does not look into architecture dependent install folders by default:

```
CMake constructs a set of possible installation prefixes for the package. Under
each prefix several directories are searched for a configuration file. The tables
below show the directories searched.

[...]

  <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/cmake/<name>*/          (U)
  <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/                (U)
  <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/  (U)

[...]

In all cases the <name> is treated as case-insensitive and corresponds to any of
the names specified (<package> or names given by NAMES). Paths with lib/<arch>
are enabled if CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE is set.
```

(from CMake 2.8.12 online documentation of the [find_package command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:find_package))

A solution consists in setting this CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE in the project root CMakeLists.txt file (in your case that would be editing src/packages/OGF/gel_python3/CMakeLists.txt) before calling find_package for PythonLibs; for instance:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(project_name)

# Check the architecture and set CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE accordingly
if(UNIX)
  if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE "x86_64-linux-gnu")
  endif()
endif()

find_package(PythonInterp 3.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.2 REQUIRED)

# Rest of your file
```

That worked in my case.